# create a new option and inject into select box using mootools 1.2

Tags: javascript, ajax, element, mootools1.2

i have one AJAX function which return the list of countries. It works fine.

My problem is that want to load that countries in on select box which is already in HTML and is empty means no option value in it.

I want to know that how can i create a new option element and inject into the select box using moo tools 1.2

I have used below code but its not working in IE.

```
var NewOption = new Option("Select Sub Category",'0');

NewOption.inject($('nSub_nIndustryID'))
```

Thanks

Avinash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i have solved it my self..

```
var newElement =  new Element('option');    
newElement.inject($('sCity'));
newElement.setProperty('value','0');
newElement.appendText('Select States first');
```

Thx for your time....

Answer (score 10):

There is no need to create a variable, unless you are going to use it later.

```
new Element('option', {'value': 0, 'text':'Select states first'}).inject($('sCity'));
```